# Easy question on how to know and use html e css in a site [html]

Tags: html, css

I'am an administrator of a website (I mean user that can access to the site with a login and I can modify the page; the site called me admin). I want to know if as admin I can modify and update this webpage from code. Since I'm admin I can modify by a textbox the information of the site (through a dashboard?), but I want to know if I have autorization to access the server files (or something like that) and I can modify page direclty from it.      I want to find a way to modify the site without insert text in the box, clicking every time in the bottom "upgrade" (as a data entry), but I would try to modify all directly from htlm code.                                  I don't know the permission and I don't directly know who has created the site, but I'm asking you if it is possible know if I'm authorized to edit the site and what is the easiest way to do this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you inspect a page and update the html code, js, text or whatever, those changes are just for you, the changes are not permanently.

To update permanently what you see when you open a page, you have to modify the server files which are hosted or if that website have a admin dashboard and the website content is customizable from admin, you can change it from there.

I hope my answer helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think i have an admin dashboard and I work from there because I'm the admin and I can modify the data from label that I can update. But I want to modify the site without clicking every time in the bottom "upgrade", and I would like to insert the data right from the html code to be faster, do you know how I can check if I can access the server files, or if I can do it in another way?